# Using bootstrap4-toggle and localStorage to toggle CSS for dark mode

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, local-storage

This has to be pretty simple; I'm trying to get `localStorage` to work with Bootstrap 4 and the additional library `bootstrap4-toggle` https://github.com/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle to toggle a CSS dark mode.

But, the class `dark` is not added to the `body-container` div, and there are no errors in the console, so I don't know what is broken.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xn23e0ob/

Libraries:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/css/bootstrap4-toggle.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/gitbrent/bootstrap4-toggle@3.6.1/js/bootstrap4-toggle.min.js"></script>
```

HTML:

```
<label class="switch">
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" onclick="darkLight()" id="checkBox">
<span class="slider"></span>
</label>

<div class="body-container">
div div 
</div>
```

Function:

```
$('.body-container').toggleClass(localStorage.toggled);

function darkLight() {
  if (localStorage.toggled != 'dark') {
    $('.body-container').toggleClass('dark', true);
    localStorage.toggled = "dark";
     
  } else {
    $('.body-container').toggleClass('dark', false);
    localStorage.toggled = "";
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.dark {
  background-color: #000000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the input handler. It should be `onchange="darkLight()"` instead of `onclick="darkLight()"`.

Comment: Thanks! That was easy. My simple mistake.